# ExtJS: Instance level item listener not skipping component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I was reading the [Declarative Listeners documentation](https://www.sencha.com/blog/declarative-listeners-in-ext-js-5/) (from [this thread's answer](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295400#post1080668)), and I'm very confused about something. The documentation states:

> On the other hand, instance-level listeners skip the component and
>   resolve to a ViewController upward in the hierarchy starting with the
>   parent Container.

With the example of:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  controller: 'main',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'user',
      listeners: {
        remove: 'onUserRemove'
      }
    }
  ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.main',
  onUserRemove: function() {
    console.log('user removed');
  }
});
```

Which tells me that the user class has its own controller, but the listeners attached to it (in the Main View class) will be resolved to the Main View's Controller. Great, that makes sense. However, what doesn't make sense is if you add items to this class, and one of these items has a listener on it... this listener apparently tries to resolve to the class's controller.

Here's an example. I have a SearchPanel class that has a ViewModel and a ViewController. The ViewController controls things like pressing the Search button and any other logic I'd desire for this class. Now, because my SearchPanel is a sort of "base" class that I'll be using across my app, I can't define its items, as they'll vary from view to view. So when I go to define my items in the instance-level config, I'm going to have listeners for some of these items. Unfortunately, it looks like these listeners try to resolve to the SearchPanel class, which is not what I want... I want them to resolve to the ViewController for the defined class.

In my [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19ja), I would like Textfield's listener to resolve to MyView's controller. You'll notice if you type in the textfield, there will be an error in the console. Is this a bug, or is this by design? If it's by design, how can I get this to work?

Comment: If I read your link, I read "
In Ext JS 4, you could only resolve string handlers if an explicit “scope” was given. In Ext JS 5, we’ve added some special rules for default scope resolution when a “string” listener is declared without an explicit scope.". Have you tried setting `scope` explicitly?

Comment: Well, in that thread, the dev basically said to not use scope like that, and I'm not sure how else I would set the scope in the view without using initComponent.